# Visual Studio 2015 auto-close braces behaviour, single line IF -> multi line IF

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

If I write this code in VS2015:

```
if(test)
  do1();
else
  do2();
```

Then I modify it, because I want the IF to be multi line, I put a open brace at the end of the if line:

```
if(test) {
  do1();
else
  do2();
```

VS will add the closing brace for me:

```
if(test) { }
  do1();
else
  do2();
```

Which I must then delete/move to where it should be.

Is there any way of having this "helpful" feature be more helpful by automatically putting the closing brace at the end of the single line statement consequence of a true test, viz:

```
if(test){
  do1();}
else
  do2();
```

Or even better:

```
if(test)
{
  do1();
}
else
  do2();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

We can go to Tools>Options…>Text Editor> All languages or Basic/C#/C/C++/other languages and uncheck/check (default status) the option “**Automatic brace completion**” to control the automatic completion behavior when you type ‘{’.  Uncheck this option will make the VS not auto add the ‘}’, so you do not need to manually delete it in this case. 
[image]

But for your expected feature, there is no such setting and you try to report this suggestion to the VS Product Team in here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. Once you done it, please share it in here and we will vote it and attract the attention of the VS Product Team.

Comment: Looks like someone (the only other person in the world who cares enough to post about it? :) ) beat me to it by approximately 3 years: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6336945-smart-auto-braces-when-refactoring-single-line-blo

Comment: @CaiusJard, sorry for this inconvience and I have already reported this suggestion to the VS Product Team again, please check this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/20286340-vs-2015-c-auto-complete-braces-behavior-single and you can vote it, we are also welcome other community members who have the same idea to vote it and attract the attention of the VS Product Team.